# How to set padding on continuous scales (eg scaleLinear) in d3.js v4?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to set bar padding in my histogram in much the same way you would if you had an ordinal scale:

```
x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([fist, last])
    .rangeRound([bottom, top])
    .padding(someFractionBetweenZeroAndOne)
```

Nope. That doesn't work. So then I head to the [API documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#continuous-scales) there's no `.padding` method on continuous scales!

Well, I *could* calculate my bar widths manually, but is there really no integrated `padding` solution available for continuous scales?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It makes *no* sense having a padding in a linear scale!

However, there are several alternatives to add some space to the bars, like using groups (as Bostock does in [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3048450)) and setting the position the rectangles inside the group in a way that it has some space to the neighbours.

Another alternative is changing the positions and dimensions of the rectangles (as you said, *"calculate my bar widths manually"*). For instance, in this demo, I'm changing the width of each bar by 90% of the width of each bin.

```js
var data = [{x:0, y:10},
            {x:2, y:40},
            {x:4, y:70},
            {x:6, y:30},
            {x:8, y:20}];

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 300)
  .attr("height", 200);

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 10])
  .range([0, 300]);

var barWidth = xScale.domain()[1]/data.length;

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 80])
  .range([200, 0]);

var bars = svg.selectAll(".bars")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect");

bars.attr("x", function(d){ return xScale(d.x)})
  .attr("y", function(d){ return yScale(d.y)})
  .attr("width", function(d,i){ return xScale(barWidth) * 0.9})
  .attr("height", function(d){ return 200 - yScale(d.y)});
```

```css
rect {
  fill: teal;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, at the moment I'm calculating the bar widths & offsets in a similar manner. More relevantly, is there hence any way to apply padding to the histogram bin function (to adjust x0 & x1) then, given that often its end-goal is to show an ordinal function on a continuous scale (i.e. what I'm trying to do)?

Comment: As far as I know, x0 and x1 are automatically generated by the histogram function. I suggest you post this specific question as another post.

Comment: Actually, I guess technically the answer is still: _it doesn't make sense_, because if you have a bin whose first bin scale is `[0,10]`, with 20% padding to give an effective display of `[1,9]` an observer may be confused whether a value of `0.5` falls n that bin.

Comment: Indeed: you cannot have spaces between class intervals (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrequencyDistribution.html). You can just manipulate the graphic outcome, but just the minimum to separate the bars.